management of number precision by terra: decimal raster values are modified when writing vector files
This question is pretty much identical to this one except mine is about vector format not raster.
When I export float numbers to a shapefile from terra:writeVector the output includes many more decimal points than the original file and the values are up to 3e-16 higher or lower than the input. I am sending the file as part of permitting processes so I cannot change the file format.
v <- vect(cbind(1:5,1:5))
crs(v) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
v$id <- 1:length(v)
v$name <- letters[1:length(v)]
v$values<-c(0.3, 3.1, 4.3, 5.0, 9.8)
v$values2<-c(329.7, 124.0, 64.2, 210.0, 254.1)
tmpfname<-paste0("name", ".shp")

p<-writeVector(v, tmpfname, overwrite=TRUE)
#this doesn't work to save the output as an object `p`
v<-vect(tmpfname)
sprintf("%.8f", v$values)
#[1] "329.70000000" "124.00000000" "64.20000000"  "210.00000000" "254.10000000"
sprintf("%.16f", v$values)
#[1] "0.3000000000000000" "3.1000000000000001" "4.2999999999999998" "5.0000000000000000" "9.8000000000000007"
sprintf("%.8f", v$values2)
#[1] "329.70000000" "124.00000000" "64.20000000"  "210.00000000" "254.10000000"
sprintf("%.16f", v$values2)
#[1] "329.6999999999999886" "124.0000000000000000" "64.2000000000000028"  "210.0000000000000000"
#[5] "254.0999999999999943"

When I load the files into QGIS (which I expect the user will do), the numbers look like this:

I tried implementing a solution with FLT8 as proposed for the raster format but couldn't find anything that worked. I'm pretty sure that FLT4 or FLT2 would be sufficient for my numbers.

Looks like is not implemented. Reading https://gdal.org/en/stable/drivers/vector/shapefile.html Real (floating point) fields without an explicit width are treated as width 24 with 15 decimal places of precision. -- it corresponds to the values shown in QGIS (and stored in .dbf). The conversion is done around https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/87b7cb2045e0be67772b1e6c0557265481451dcc/src/write_ogr.cpp#L437. Even write.dbf() function from {foreign} package converts reals to numbers with 15 char precission: https://github.com/cran/foreign/blob/master/R/dbf.R.
